# Access an authorisation flag from View Data in JavaScript (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side, viewdata

I have an `onclick` which should not be available to anonymous users.

I currently hacked it together by using a flag element:

```
@if (ViewBag.User != null)
{
    <div id="userAuthenticated"></div>                        
}
```

and in jQuery:

```
$('.whatever').click(function() {
    if ($('#userAuthenticated').length) {
         // ... do something
    }
});
```

This just feels kinda nasty, but I'm not aware of any better way of doing it. What is best practice for handling this scenario. Is there some neat trick that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, I would suggest having two separate javascript files, `mysite-authorized.js` and `mysite-anon.js`, and exclude any functions for authorized users only from the anon file.  Then, in your layout file, set the js file to be served based on the authorization level.

This way, you avoid any authorization flags, whch can be avoided by a savvy user.

P.S.

In your view, you already have a means to check for authorization:

```
if (this.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // authenticated user js file here
}
else
{
    // anon user js file here
}
```

Comment: I thought this was a bad idea on first read but having thought about it I can probably work something like this without introducing any code duplication. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Many of my ideas seem bad at first (some remain so at second, third, ... ).  Here, you can use this as an opportunity to place your javascript code into two or three separate js files, a base file with functionality needed for all users, an authorized file, which contains functionality specific to authorized users, and if there is any functionality unique to anonymous users, a file for that as well.  If this was helpful, please mark as answered.

Comment: Well I'd prefer not to have to serve multiple files, but I've gone this route for now and it works quite nicely. Thanks.